# Exterior Product $d\Phi_1\wedge d\Phi_2$ and spherical coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates, exterior-algebra

One short question:

> > If $\Phi\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$, defined by
> >     $$
> > \begin{pmatrix}r\\\vartheta\\\phi\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}r\sin \vartheta\cos \phi\\r\sin \vartheta \sin\phi\\r\cos\vartheta\end{pmatrix},
> > $$
> >     what are then the exterior products
> >     $$
> > d\Phi_1\wedge d\Phi_2,~~~~~~~~~~d\Phi_1\wedge d\Phi_3,~~~~~~~~~~d\Phi_2\wedge d\Phi_3?
> > $$

Comment: Do you know what $\mathrm d\Phi_1$, $\mathrm d\Phi_2$ and $\mathrm d\Phi_3$ are?

Comment: Yes, that are differentials.

Comment: Can you write the differential at $(r,\theta,\phi)$ of the components of $\Phi$?

Comment: I do not exactly know what you mean...

Comment: Can you write down a formula that, given the coordinates $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$, gives $\mathrm d\Phi_1$?

Comment: I wrote it in my answer: please, let me know if you need more details, ok? I would gladly add them, if requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$d\Phi_1:=\frac{\partial \Phi_1}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial \Phi_1}{\partial \theta}d\theta+\frac{\partial \Phi_1}{\partial \phi}d\phi=
\sin\theta\cos\phi dr+r\cos\theta\cos\phi d\theta-r\sin\theta \sin\phi d\phi,$$

and similarly for the other components $\Phi_2$, $\Phi_3$ of $\Phi$, i.e.

$$d\Phi_2:=\frac{\partial \Phi_2}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial \Phi_2}{\partial \theta}d\theta+\frac{\partial \Phi_2}{\partial \phi}d\phi=
\sin\theta\sin\phi dr+r\cos\theta\sin\phi d\theta+r\sin\theta\cos\phi d\phi,$$

$$d\Phi_3:=\frac{\partial \Phi_3}{\partial r}dr+\frac{\partial \Phi_3}{\partial \theta}d\theta+\frac{\partial \Phi_3}{\partial \phi}d\phi=
\cos\theta dr-r\sin\theta d\theta,$$

as $\frac{\partial \Phi_3}{\partial \phi}=\frac{\partial r\cos\theta}{\partial \phi}=0.$

To arrive at the answer you need to remember that, by definition of wedge product

$$dx_i\wedge dx_j=-dx_j\wedge dx_i,$$

for all $i,j=1,2,3$ with $x_1=r$, $x_2=\theta$ and $x_3=\phi$. In particular

$$dr\wedge dr=d\theta\wedge d\theta=d\phi\wedge d\phi=0.~(*)$$

Moreover $f(r,\theta,\phi)dx_i\wedge g(r,\theta,\phi)dx_j:= f(r,\theta,\phi)g(r,\theta,\phi)dx_i\wedge dx_j$, for all functions $f$ and $g$.

Let us compute $d\Phi_1\wedge d\Phi_2$: using the above formulae we have

$$d\Phi_1\wedge d\Phi_2=(\sin\theta\sin\phi dr+r\cos\theta\sin\phi d\theta+r\sin\theta\cos\phi d\phi)\wedge(\sin\theta\sin\phi dr+r\cos\theta\sin\phi d\theta+r\sin\theta\cos\phi d\phi); $$

the wedge product $\wedge$ is linear: using the property $(*)$ we collect only the non trivial contributions arriving at

$$d\Phi_1\wedge d\Phi_2=r\sin\theta\sin\phi \cos\theta\sin\phi dr\wedge d\theta+
r \sin^2\theta\sin\phi \cos\phi dr\wedge d\phi+\\
r\cos\theta \sin\theta \sin^2\phi d\theta\wedge dr+
r^2\cos\theta   r\sin\theta \sin\phi \cos\phi d\theta\wedge d\phi+\\
r\sin^2\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi  d\phi\wedge dr  +
r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi  d\phi \wedge d\theta; $$

using $dr\wedge d\theta=-d\theta\wedge dr$ etc...we arrive at the final result, i.e.

$$d\Phi_1\wedge d\Phi_2=(r\sin\theta\sin\phi \cos\theta\sin\phi-r\cos\theta \sin\theta \sin^2\phi) dr\wedge d\theta+
(r \sin^2\theta\sin\phi \cos\phi-r\sin^2\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi  )  dr\wedge d\phi+\\
(r^2\cos\theta   r\sin\theta \sin\phi \cos\phi-r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi ) d\theta\wedge d\phi. $$

Comment: Ok, I have $d\Phi_2=\sin\vartheta\sin\phi dr+\cos\vartheta r \sin\phi d\vartheta + \cos\phi r \sin\vartheta d\phi$. But still I do not know what the exterior produkt $d\Phi_1\wedge d\Phi_2 $ is. Hm, sorry.

Comment: I add it to my answer :)

Comment: I think I got it already :D

Comment: Damn, I was too slow...too many controbutions :) In any case, well done! Feel free to upvote and flag the answer if it was helpful to you :) Thanks a lot!